# Quick Ratio Test Question

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

So I was given the following prompt:

"Test the convergence or divergence of the following series."

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{n!}{2*5*8*...*(3n+2)})$

I guess I'm a bit confused about what the limit would look like in this specific context. I understand that the ratio test needs to be used here and that the limit might look like the following: $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(3n+3)}}{\frac{n!}{3n+2}}$, but I guess I'm a bit confused about how to find this limit. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(n+1) !}{3(n+1)+2}}{\frac{n !}{3 n+2}}\right| \\
\begin{array}{l}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mid \frac{(n+1) !(3 n+2)}{(3 n+5)(n !)} \\
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{n(3 n+2)}{(3 n+5)}\right|
\end{array} \mid \\
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{3 n^{2}+2 n}{3 n+5}\right|
\end{array}
\end{equation}

This limit diverges.